How does copy-on-write ensure the thread safety?
When I was looking for how to implement copy-on-write in C++, I saw the implementation as below:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct SPersonData
{
    string m_name;
    string m_surname;
};

class CPerson
{
public:
    shared_ptr<SPersonData> m_data;

    string getName() const;
    string getSurname() const;

    void rename (const string&, const string&);
};

string CPerson::getName() const
{
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_name;
    return string();
}

string CPerson::getSurname() const
{ 
    if (m_data) return m_data->m_surname;
    return string();
}

void CPerson::rename (const string &name, const string &surname)
{
    if (!((m_data) && m_data.unique()))
        m_data = make_shared<SPersonData>(); 

    m_data->m_name = name;
    m_data->m_surname = surname;
}

However, I am very curious of that how it ensure the thread safety. First, I know the shared_ptr is not thread-safe so it may cause the object in shared_ptr released improperly if other threads are accessing the shared_ptr at the same time when some threads are changing shared_ptr as below.
if (!((m_data) && m_data.unique()))
m_data = make_shared<SPersonData>(); 

Secondly, on rename() method, changing shared_ptr and assigning value are not atomic so if other threads try accessing the shared_ptr value in between the thread changes the shared_ptr and assignes the value, they may get the wrong value.
How to correctly implement copy-on-write in C++?

Who said this code was thread-safe?

because I saw copy-on-write is thread-safe

COW is no more inherently thread safe than any other approach.   The only difference between COW and other approaches is that it defers copying of key data as long as possible.    That doesn't eliminate the need to ensure correct sequencing (e.g. use of synchronisation) if instances of your class are accessed/modified by multiple threads - it may change which sections of code need to address sequencing.

@Peter Got it, I see now that I had mixed up the concepts.

My coworker implented a copy_on_write pointer here, which you can peruse for reference: https://github.com/stlab/libraries/blob/main/stlab/copy_on_write.hpp

Here shallow copies of CPerson can be used freely across different threads, but single instance of CPerson is not thread safe (can't use same instance of variable across different threads without synchronization).

Checking for uniqueness is difficult in a thread-safe manor. In single threaded programs shared_ptr::use_count or  shared_ptr::unique can be used. But in a multi-threaded environment, such simple approach leads to UB. You need a more complex tango, because between this thread checking for uniqueness and modifying the unique-assumed object, another thread may try to copy and you get corrupt data in that copy.
